# Diferença no Sem Resposta e Unanswered

Tags: suporte

Reparei que o botão de `Sem Resposta` do ptSO retorna apenas perguntas com 0 respostas enquanto que o `Unanswered` do SO retorna perguntas sem solução.

É assim mesmo ou olhei errado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei se você está na interface nova do SO (en), que mudou um pouco isso. Mas são duas coisas diferentes. Em home > sem resposta, você tem as perguntas com 0 respostas. Em perguntas > sem resposta (aba), você tem as perguntas sem resposta aceita.

É realmente confuso e desnecessário. Espero que as mudanças de interface que estão em testes no SO resolvam isso.

Comment: Home > sem resposta tem a URL: `http://pt.stackoverflow.com/unanswered`

Comment: Perguntas > rem resposta tem a URL: `http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered`

Comment: Pra mim ambas tem o mesmo resultado no ptSO

Comment: No SO (en) é diferente os resultados

Comment: Quantas páginas de resultado você vê em casa link? Pra mim um tem 77 páginas, e o outro tem 119.

Comment: Descobri o problema, quando eu vou pelo Home no ptSO ele abre na aba de `nenhuma resposta` e quando eu vou pelo Home no SO (en) ele abre na aba de `vote`... que loucura salvo assim aheauheuhae

Comment: De fato confuso, mas me equivoquei também.